# What does the QuickTbl function do in this code?

Tags: r, function

I'm wondering how the author of the following page define the `"QuickTbl"` function. I assumed that it’s a user-defined function, rather than a function included in a library. I could not find any definition for the `QuickTbl` function.

https://alphahive.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/asset-pricing-9b-regime-switching/

If you look at the blog above, in MarkovEstPlot, QuickTbl is used as follows:

```
gg.m.tbl <- QuickTbl(mean.tbl,title='Estimates of Mean')
```

This should be defined somewhere in the blog (or in a library), but I could not find any.

(I am now asking the author for his/her help as well).

Comment: I am not sure this is answerable, or at least is is merely just a matter of opinion. However, to improve the question, I suggest you copy example code from the blog post to here, and perhaps add your own educated guesses as to what that function does. Presently if that link breaks (and they often do) the question here gives no other information to go on at all.

Comment: If you look at the blog I mentioned, in MarkovEstPlot, QuickTbl is used as follows: gg.m.tbl <- QuickTbl(mean.tbl,title='Estimates of Mean')
      This should be defined somewhere in the blog (or in a library),  but I could not find any.

Comment: Yes, sure. Can you add that into your post? Imagine that the blog post is deleted tomorrow - what can you add to your post to ensure that it will still make sense? I imagine one line on its own might not be enough, but if you can capture the context of what the code does, maybe someone can work out what that function does.

Comment: Noted, thanks, halfer, for your help!

Comment: install.packages("basictabler")
library(basictabler)

and replacing QuickTbl by qtbl seems to work now.

For the basictabler library including qtbl function, please refer to:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/basictabler/vignettes/v01-introduction.html

Comment: ^ If that's an answer, would you post it in an answer box? We welcome self-answers here `:=)`

Answer (score 0):

install.packages("basictabler")
library(“basictabler”)

and replacing QuickTbl by qtbl seems to work now.

For the basictabler library including qtbl function, please refer to: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/basictabler/vignettes/v01-introduction.html